# Clientdataset fechando após abrir

Tags: delphi

Estou utilizando o delphi xe6 faz alguns dias e estou quebrando a cabeça com um problema.
Tenho aqui o trio: **SQLDataSet -> ClientDataSet -> DataSetProvider**.

Quando abro meu formulário, chamo o `cdsPessoas.Open` (ClientDataSet).

Até aí tudo bem, ele exibe meus registros tudo certo. Mas na hora que eu chamo o `cdsPessoas.Append`, ele me retorna o erro dizendo que o ClientDataSet não está ativo. O problema é que em nenhum momento eu fecho ele, ou seja, não sei por que diabos ele está fechando sozinho.

Utilizo esses componentes dentro de um data module junto com mais dois ClientDataSet e SQLDataSet fazendo o **Master\Detail**. Já tentei tirar o master\detail, mas não é o problema, até porque os dados são exibidos corretamente.

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: Transcrevendo o comentário do usuário @Ewerton-dutra, "Seria bom você passar parte do código, pois você está falando que não está fechando. Mas talvez você está fazendo alguma coisa que esteja fechando."

Comment: Atualize a questão com um pouco de código. Mas pelos sintomas apresentados, eu diria que um `Open` no `cdsPessoas` antes do `Append` resolveria... Usar componentes a partir de um Data Module, assim como de um formulário desenhado, geram vários problemas por ocultarem o código. É difícil ter certeza dos valores das propriedades quando inicia a execução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando as informações fornecidas, não sou capaz de apontar uma resposta direta ao problema, então procurarei ajudar de outra forma, com uma ideia.

Em situações como esta o que eu faço é compilar a aplicação com **Debug DCUs** ativo e colocar um tratador de evento, neste caso, em **AfterClose** do Dataset em questão. Então recrio a situação de problema e quando o Delphi parar no *breakpoint* eu avalio o **CallStack**, que nesse caso vai mostrar toda a sequência de chamadas que culminou com a situação.

Normalmente eu encontro um código meu, um tratador de evento que tinha esquecido ou mesmo um *bug* que é responsável pelo caso. Algumas vezes trata-se de um comportamento normal do componente que eu não havia compreendido bem ou então o uso de uma propriedade da forma errada.

Seja como for, com o **CallStack** eu geralmente consigo entender o que está provocando o comportamento estranho e resolvo o caso.

Experimente!